# Javascript inductance calculation

Tags: javascript

I've got this formula: L=P (N^2 + N ) / 1.25 + 0.7 x F

I need to write it in Javascript, I've got general error checking code, then I get to the point of calculating the inductance.

```
var N = parseFloat($("#Number").val());
var P = parseFloat($("#Perimeter").val());
var F = parseFloat($("#Feeder").val());
var L = P (Math.pow(N,2) + N) / 1.25 + 0.7 * F
$("#result").html(L);
```

I tested just adding the variables to start, now I added the formula in, but no result shows.

Comment: do you have an element with an ID of *result*?

Comment: At a glance, it looks like you're missing the * after the P in your final expression.

Comment: @Mansoor If you have an answer, please put it as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo I'll keep that mind. :P

Comment: Thank you all for the help and feedback. I checked with the person I got the formula from, there was indeed a * missing after the P.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `*` here:

```
var L = P (Math.pow(N,2) + N) / 1.25 + 0.7 * F
```

Try:

```
var L = P * (Math.pow(N,2) + N) / 1.25 + 0.7 * F
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an operator after `P`:

```
var L = P * (Math.pow(N,2) + N) / 1.25 + 0.7 * F
```

I'm not sure about the proper order here (it's been a while since Phys II), so you may want to add some parentheses to be sure the operations happen in the order they should.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `*` here without which javascript is treating `P (Math.pow(N,2) + N)` as a call to a function `P` with parameter as `Math.pow(N,2) + N`

Try this:

```
var L = P * (Math.pow(N,2) + N) / 1.25 + 0.7 * F
```